# Python dictionary swapping element value through iteration

Tags: python, dictionary, memory-leaks

### PROBLEM

I'm building a video-editor like in python. I have created timeline which use dictionary for storing animation object. When I go to render phase, I have to render the movie which is a big timeline of scene which are also timeline. So we have at least 2 dictionary per movie. When i iterate throught the scene, i iterate throught the dictionary, and render the scene :

```
timeline = self.tl.timeline_object.items() # get the items of the dictionary
for scene in timeline:
    print(timeline, id(timeline))
    scene[1]()                             # do all the render stuff
```

which give the following result :

```
dict_items([('1', <class 'test_movie.first_scene.FirstScene'>), ('2', <class 'test_movie.second_scene.SecondScene'>)]) 140043388706584
dict_items([('1', <animations.FillScreen.FillScreen object at 0x7f5e643a67f0>), ('2', <animations.Write.Write object at 0x7f5e643a69b0>)]) 140043388706584
```

as you can see the dictionary swap between the movie's one and the scene's one (look at the id).

I should get the first line :

```
dict_items([('1', <class 'test_movie.first_scene.FirstScene'>), ('2', <class 'test_movie.second_scene.SecondScene'>)]) 140043388706584
```

for the second iteration.

### QUESTION

Why do i get the dictionary of the scene instead of the "real" dictionary stored in `timeline` ? and how to solve this problem ?

### PLUS : Full code

The code is very long and a lot of objects are involved, i have tried to show you the maximum without loosing you. If you want the actual repo : https://gitlab.com/planchon/psVidTex

Otherwise, here are the important files :

```
class MovieName(Movie):
    def __init__(self):
        Movie.__init__(self)

    # add the scene to the movie timeline (dictionnary + time array)
    def prepare(self):
        self.add_to_timeline(FirstScene, 0, 10)
        self.add_to_timeline(SecondScene, 10, 20)
```

```
class Timeline(object):
    timeline_object = {}
    timeline        = []
    timeline_index  = []

    max_id = 0

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    # ajoute un element dans la timeline retourne la timeline_id de l'object
    # prend des frames comme unité de mesure du temps
    def add_object(self, animation, start, end, position):
        animation_id = self.get_global_id()
        self.timeline_object[animation_id] = animation                      
        self.add_into_timeline(start, [start, end, position, animation_id]) 

        return animation_id

    # add the tuple [start, end, position, animation_id] into the timeline
    def add_into_timeline(self, start, element):
        index = bisect.bisect(self.timeline_index, start)
        self.timeline_index.insert(index, start)
        self.timeline.insert(index, element)

    # get the next id
    def get_global_id(self):
        self.max_id = self.max_id + 1
        return str(self.max_id)
```

```
class FirstScene(Scene):
    def __init__(self):
        Scene.__init__(self)

    def prepare(self):
        self.add_to_timeline(FillScreen("col"), 0, 10)
        self.add_to_timeline(Write("test"), 0, 10)
```

```
class Movie(object):
    tl = Timeline()

    def __init__(self):
        self.prepare()
        self.init_all_scene()

    def render(self):
        pass

    def prepare(self):
        pass

    def init_all_scene(self):
        timeline = self.tl.timeline_object.items()
        for scene in timeline:
            print(timeline, id(timeline))
            scene[1]()

    # add the scene to the timeline
    def add_to_timeline(self, scene, start, end):
        return self.tl.add_object(scene, start, end, 0)
```

```
class Scene(Container):
    tl = Timeline()

    def __init__(self, **kargs):
        self.prepare()

    def add_to_timeline(self, anim, start, end):
        return self.tl.add_object(anim, start, end, 0)

    def prepare(self):
        pass

    def render(self):
        pass
```

The `Write` and `FillScreen` are not relevant object in this context. You can find them in the repo if necessary.

Comment: can you please upload your full ! code so we will understand the question

Comment: Without a minimal example of the dictionary that you are iterating over, it is impossible for anyone to test. The example doesn't need to be the actual dictionary just a dictionary that will demonstrate the problem - please read [mcve]. However your *print* should always print the same thing (`timeline`) UNLESS `scene[1]()` is modifying that object in some way.

Comment: I have added all the file. If you need anything, ask me

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the Timeline class was not properly initialize and the `timeline_object` was shared between all the differents timeline.

So to resolved, i just modified the class Timeline :

```
class Timeline(object):    
    def __init__(self):
        self.timeline_object = {}
        self.timeline        = []
        self.timeline_index  = []
        self.max_id          = 0
```

by changing the position of the arrays in the init, that way they are local to the object and not to the meta-object...